# jQuery chosen dropdown dissable when checkbox is enabled

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm  really new in jQuery and i'm having difficulties figuring out how to disable a drop down list by id when a checkbox is checked.

The logic would look like this.

1) If a checkbox is enabled (checked) then disable drop down
2) If a checkbox is disabled (unchecked) then enable the drop down

The checkbox id for example is Trivial_Order and the Dropdown id is manager_search

```js
var select = $('select');
select.chosen();
select.on('chosen:updated', function () {
    if (select.attr('readonly')) {
        var wasDisabled = select.is(':disabled');

        select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        select.data('chosen').search_field_disabled();

        if (wasDisabled) {
            select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            select.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
});
select.trigger('chosen:updated');
```

```css
select {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.proto.min.js"></script>

<select readonly="readonly">
    <option>option</option>
</select>
```

I just can't figure out how to implement this checkbox logic in this code.

The Jquery plugin that i'm using is Chosen 1.7.0

Could anyone please help?

UPDATE: I don't understand what i'm doing wrong. It does not work

```
    <script>

        var myselect = $('select');
        myselect.chosen();
        $('chosen-change').change(function () {
            myselect.prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
            myselect.trigger("chosen:updated");
        });

    </script>


<td>Checkbox:</td>
<td>
<asp:CheckBox ID="Trivial_Order" runat="server" 
oncheckedchanged="Trivial_Order_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True"  />



<asp:dropdownlist onkeypress="KeyPress(this.selectedIndex, this.name);return false;" id="ISS_manager"
  class="chosen-select"
  onChange="pressing='';" size="4" Runat="server">
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to trigger the `chosen:updated` event when checkbox is changed. See [Observing, Updating, and Destroying Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events) section for details. Try to run code snipeet below.

```js
var myselect=$('select');
myselect.chosen();
$('input').change(function() {
  myselect.prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
  myselect.trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.proto.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" />
<select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

**Note.**

1. You use `AutoPostBack="True"` on the `<asp:CheckBox>` control. Therefore, a request will be automatically sended to the server if the checkbox control is clicked. As a result, the browser will render a new page received from the server. Thus, the created javascript handler will not been finished.
2. You try to run javascript when wanted objects was not created in DOM.
3. There is no `chosen-change` element.

To avoid the collisions:

1. Do not use automatically post back on the `<asp:CheckBox>` control.
2. The `<script>` element must be **below** your chechbox and select elements.
3. Change event handler must be attachment to the checkbox input.

Comment: But your code will not work with the chosen plugin. Can you implement your logic to my code snippet? If checkbox is checked disable drop down if  checkbox is unchecked enable drop down. Because i implemented your code in to my project and the search feature witch is implemented in chosen does not work

Comment: @GediminasPetkus, I don't sure that logic is proper, but now it seems like you asked.

Comment: I updated the question, i'm still having difficulties i don't understand what i'm doing wrong. I'm new in jquery.. Sorry

Comment: @GediminasPetkus, in first, please run the snippet. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @GediminasPetkus, I have updated my answer. Also you could check using browser what is HTML generates your `<asp:CheckBox>` and `<asp:dropdownlist>` controls. I believe that you will succeed.

Comment: @GediminasPetkus, if it's working, then close the topic.